# Should I be receiving emails from my squadmates?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I downloaded the iOS free app for Mass Effect 3, which you can use for seeing the codex, and send ships to increase galactic readiness, among other things. Fun little app.

[image]

However, one feature was that I was going to receive mails from squadmates as I interacted with them in-game.

[image]

I am well advanced in the game, already romanced someone, but I've yet to receive a message.

[image]

I am logged in with Origin.

Is this a bug? Should I do something in the game to start receiving them? Is the AppStore description a lie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See that Mail Icon with the arrow in picture 3?  You need to click it to have the app pull all the "emails" from the server.

Comment: Heh... I feel a little dumb

Comment: @JuanManuel: No, the developers should feel a little dumb. It's a bad interface to not auto-load and/or label icons.